# What happened to my strings.xml in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio

I edited the strings.xml for my project in Android Studio by adding some more, but when I closed it and came back the next morning, it's all gone, showing a message, "Edit translations for all locales in the translations editor."

So I opened the editor, since there was a link to it right beside the message, and all the deleted strings were there.

I don't need translations, so I checked the 'untranslatable' checkbox on the right. But that didn't do anything.

How do I get back all my strings?

It's a tone of work and I don't want to rewrite everything again.

Comment: Are you sure you were editing in the `res/values` directory and not the auto-generated build directory that doesn't save your changes?

Comment: I suppose, it's right time to start using git, br0

Comment: have you built your app successfully before that?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, the strings.xml is indeed within the res/values directory, but the file itself was 'auto-generated' when I first created the project.

Comment: @MounirElfassi Unfortunately, no. This is my first android project and I'm going through a lot of troubles on the way lol

Comment: There is a local changes or version history (can't remember the exact words) option in the top toolbar somewhere. I've never used it, but worth a look

Comment: i agree @cricket_007, ==> Right click on your project in project structure on the left. then Local History -> Show History. If you want to show history only for res folder, click on it.. the same for layout folder etc..

Comment: I looked at the local history, but it only shows identical files, even if I revert it back to the time when it was last saved. Do you guys have any other ideas to get the data back from the Translations Editor???